# getProductCount() function returning similar result for every category

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks

Hello I am trying to get category name and category product count using  category Id . In my results I am getting exact category name but product count is duplicating.

```
foreach ($category as $categoryId) {
    if (!is_null($categoryId)) {
        $categoryLoadData = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $categoryArray[$count]['id'] = $categoryId;
        $categoryArray[$count]['name'] = $categoryLoadData->getName();
        $categoryArray[$count]['productCount'] = $categoryLoadData->getProductCount();
        Mage::log($categoryId.' - '.$categoryLoadData->getName().' - '.$categoryLoadData->getProductCount(),null,'final.log'
                                . '');
        $count++;
      }
 }
    Mage::log($categoryArray,null,'catrblock.log');
```

I got result in final.log

```
14 - category_name_1 - 74
7 - category_name_2 - 74
```

Result I got in catrblock.log

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
 (
     [id] => 14
     [name] => category_name_1
     [productCount] => 74
 )

 [1] => Array
 (
     [id] => 7
     [name] => category_name_2
     [productCount] => 74
 )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the problem here is that you're using a singleton:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
```

Thus, even if you reload the singleton in a loop, there can be some persistent data in your object.

You should use models instead:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
```

If you need clarification about when to use singletons, I reckon you should check this very good SE post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756753/magento-getsingleton-vs-getmodel-issue

Comment: Thanks a lot  Digital Pianism it worked for me . Thank you for the description

Comment: @PRashantPUrohit no problem, see my edit for more details about the use of singletons.

Comment: Digital Pianism thank you for the link it will help me a lot just a request can you up vote my question if you can :)